# Java adding data to a nested array

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I use the same arraylist row to add values into the nested array tableValues since the clear command removes the data in row.

Thanks

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tableValues = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> row = new ArrayList<String>();

    row.add("a");
    row.add("b");
    row.add("c");
    tableValues.add(row);
    row.clear();

    row.add("d");
    row.add("e");
    row.add("f");
    tableValues.add(row);
    row.clear();

    row.add("g");
    row.add("h");
    row.add("i");
    tableValues.add(row);
    row.clear();

    System.out.println(tableValues);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you *really* want to add three *different* ArrayLists, so change each `row.clear()` to:

```
row = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Why would you *want* to "use the same arraylist row to add values"? I can't see why you'd want your top-level `ArrayList` to basically contain the same reference three times. Why would you *not* want them to be references to independent lists?

Comment: What I meant was I didn't want to have row1, row2 row3 etc since I don't know how many rows there are, so that would cause a problem :)

Comment: @Ricco: Right - it's worth differentiating between *objects* and *variables*. You're now using one variable, but it will have three different values over its lifetime. (I'd be tempted to refactor the "add a row" part into a separate method, but that's a slightly different topic where I'd need more context.)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
ArrayList<String> row;

row = new ArrayList<String>();
// fill row
tableValues.add(row);

row = new ArrayList<String>();
// fill row
tableValues.add(row);
```

This way you don't need in your code variable for each row.
or put it in cycle

```
while(codnition) { // or for or do {} while(condition);
   List<String> row = new  ArrayList<String>();
   // fill row
   table.add(row);
}
```

This way there single name for currently added row, but scope of this variable is only inside given iteration of cycle.